# WPF DataTrigger to set the Width Window property

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I want to set the width property of Window depending on the value of a ViewModel property. First I have a ContentControl:

and then:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type massedit:SimpleFieldVM}">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding .}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <!-- Without selector, only with DataTriggers select my ContentControl -->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.ENum}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ComboboxEnumTemplate}" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.List}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ComboboxListTemplate}" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.Bit}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BitTemplate}" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.Date}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DateTemplate}" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.DatTime}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DatTimeTemplate}" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.Time}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TimeTemplate}" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

But change the property Width of my ContentControl. I want to change the property Width of my Window!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind Window.Width directly or you could use FitToContent property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743733%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

FitToContent will try to fit the Window to its content means if you manage to set the content to desired size the window will follow. :)